# How to identify filebeat source in logstash logs

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I have multiple filebeat services running on different applications, which send the logs to a central logstash server for parsing.
Sometimes a few application logs are not in correct format so there is a 'parse error' in the 'logstash-plain.log' file. The problem I am having is that I am not able to identify from logstash-plain.log file where the logs are coming from (since there are a huge number of applications with filebeat running)

Is there a way to trace the filebeat source from logstash logs?

Comment: does ``hostname`` store the host of filebeat?

Answer (score 0):

You can use processors from filebeat to [add tags](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/add-tags.html)

```
processors:
  - add_tags:
      tags: [my_app_1]
      target: "application_tags"
```

and then use different filter plugins configuration in logstash to parse the logs properly.

```
filter {
    if "my_app_1" in [application_tags] {
        grok {
           ....
        }     
    }
}
```